# Get g bounding box in svg units

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to implement a *menu* in *Javascript* with single *menu-items* being `svg:g`.
To mark an item as selected I would like to move another `svg:g` on top of the *menu-item*.

For this I need to get the bounding box of the *menu-item* (=`svg:g`) so I can apply the rect (x, y, width, height) to the other. I have not found a convenient way yet, for getting the bounding box of a `svg:g`.

The only way I can think of would be recursing into the children and calculating the bounding box (approximation) by hand. Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to use the [`getBBox`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox) method of your group element.
e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/PFnre/1/

```js
var root = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
document.body.appendChild(root);

var g = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
root.appendChild(g);

var r = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
r.setAttribute("x", "50");
r.setAttribute("y", "60");
r.setAttribute("width", "100");
r.setAttribute("height", "110");
r.setAttribute("fill", "blue");
g.appendChild(r);

var c = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
c.setAttribute("cx", "150");
c.setAttribute("cy", "140");
c.setAttribute("r", "60");
c.setAttribute("fill", "red");
g.appendChild(c);

var bbox = g.getBBox();

var o = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
o.setAttribute("x", bbox.x);
o.setAttribute("y", bbox.y);
o.setAttribute("width", bbox.width);
o.setAttribute("height", bbox.height);
o.setAttribute("stroke", 'black')
o.setAttribute("fill", 'none');
root.appendChild(o);
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly all the `transform` and `matrix` handling in SVG made it too complicated too quickly. Now I recreate the SVG with html and there it is far less complicated.